# Change temporary directory in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to change the temporary directory in Rails 4. The default is `"#{Rails.root}/tmp"` but I would like to change it to something else, e.g.: `"/tmp"`.

I have found how to change the cache directories from `"#{Rails.root}/tmp"`:

```
config.cache_store = :file_store, '...'
config.assets.cache_store = :file_store, '...'
```

Sprockets seems to still be using the default tmp directory for caching.

In my Rails 3 project, I added the following in my `config/application.rb`:

```
if ENV['RAILS_TMP'].present?
  config.cache_store = :file_store, ENV['RAILS_TMP'] + '/cache/'
  config.assets.cache_store = :file_store, ENV['RAILS_TMP'] + '/assets'
  config.sass.cache = false
end
```

Setting RAILS_TMP causes the tmp dir to change. I have an odd feeling that this is now hard coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that some libraries like to hard code values... See: [[1]](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/172fb4259611d0720c90dfa9836df06c1a600cb4/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L101)

By adding the following you can get around the hard coded value:

```
  config.assets.cache_limit = 50.megabytes

  config.assets.configure do |env|
    env.cache = Sprockets::Cache::FileStore.new(
        File.join(ENV['RAILS_TMP'], 'cache/assets'),
        config.assets.cache_limit,
        env.logger
    )
  end
```

Comment: doh! Someone should send a patch to sprockets-rails to fix that.

Comment: it looks like there's another hard-coded tmp here, is that going to be a problem? https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/8332e530c39eba5703e5af25450f2ce80b67fdde/test/test_helper.rb#L19

Comment: @jrochkind That is not a concern because the referenced code is in sprockets-rails tests, which has no effect to the library user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this will work properly, but in `./config/application.rb`, try:

```
config.paths.add("tmp", with: ENV['RAILS_TMP'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new initializer file something like over_ride_temp_path.rb and paste the following code in it.

```
class Dir

  def self.tmpdir
    <path of the directory to be used as temp>
  end

end
```

Comment: This changes the Ruby temporary directory, but not the temporary directory used by Rails, as asked in the question.